# How To Eliminate Duplicates of Following SQL Data Values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to eliminate NIC Number duplicate situation.please provide me SQL Query for that.

[image]

Comment: You need to try something. No code, no help (but that's not a promise). That's how she blows around here, matey.

Comment: Which one do you want?  Subject_ID_001 or Subject_ID_002?

Comment: Agreed; what have you tried, and what do you want your results to look like afterwards?  What problem are you having - we are a "help you when stuck" site, not a "do all work for me" site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
DELETE FROM Table_Name A
INNER JOIN (SELECT NIC, COUNT(*) AS RecCount, MIN(RESULT) AS OlderValue 
            FROM Table_Name 
            GROUP BY NIC) b
ON A.NIC = b.NIC 
AND a.RESULT != b.OlderValue
```

Comment: @Sameera yep thats right I get you now what other column do you have in your table ??

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT NIC FROM TABLE_NAME
              HAVING COUNT(NIC) > 1)
DELETE TOP 1 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE NIC IN (SELECT NIC FROM TABLE_NAME HAVING COUNT(NIC) > 1) ORDER BY SubjectID DESC
```

Comment: .... really?  Deleting one row at a time, after scanning the table _each time_?  While I imagine this works.... #shudder#

Comment: Assuming that this is a one time purge, just git er done.  When I actually had to do this, I used ROW_NUMBER and partition and deleted everything that wasn't a 1.  Obviously for SQL Server